# ImageMagick: How to thicken lines

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I'm trying to thicken lines with imagemagick. There is a description about how to do this [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#thicken), but when I do it on my sample images they just stay the same or get rather weaker.

Examples given from imagemagick (that do not make lines thicker when I try):

```
convert man.gif -morphology Thicken '3x1+2+0:1,0,0' thick_right.gif
convert man_line.gif -morphology Thicken ConvexHull thick_line.gif
```

[image: My Sample image]

- Does anyone know how to make the lines (or shapes) thicker/bolder?
- also: how does the "command" '3x1+2+0:1,0,0' work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems these "morphology"s are were made having a black background as a basis. Once the image is white-on-black, the transformation works. From the documentation:

> It was original developed with binary (pure black and white) images in
>   mind

Negate the colors (so that I have white on black):

```
convert black-on-white.png -negate white-on-black.png
```

Then do above transformation from the question. However, I had better results with following morphology:

```
convert white-on-black.png -morphology Dilate Octagon fat-white-on-black.png
```

Still, nice to have would be to have it work from different color schemes.

Comment: The article also says * 'Dilate' and 'Erode' are dual*, so you can operate on your original image with `-morphology Erode Octagon `.

Comment: convert black-on-white.png -morphology Erode Disk:2.0 fat-black-on-white.png